# After code signing and notarizing, my program that builds with electron-builder not opening.(MacOS ARM)

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, electron-builder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poDS6.png)

if I open from terminal:

open TopCreator.app
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x600002205530 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}

I tried to add this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const electron_notarize = require('electron-notarize');

module.exports = async function (params) {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        return console.log('Platform si now MacOS')
    }

    let appId = '***'

    let appPath = path.join(
        params.appOutDir,
        `${params.packager.appInfo.productFilename}.app`
    )
    if (!fs.existsSync(appPath)) {
        console.log('File not exist')
        return
    }

    console.log(`Notarizing ${appId} found at ${appPath} with Apple ID ${process.env.APPLE_ID}`)

    try {
        await electron_notarize.notarize({
            appBundleId: appId,
            appPath: appPath,
            appleId: process.env.APPLE_ID,
            appleIdPassword: process.env.APPLE_ID_PASSWORD
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }

    console.log(`Done notarizing ${appId}`)
}
```

it notarize succesfully, but program not opening.